# What is this anti-pattern called?

Tags: design-patterns, language-agnostic, terminology, anti-patterns

Let's say I have a function called `send_welcome_email()` and a class called `User` (implemented in Python but hopefully easy to understand for non-Python devs):

```
class User:
    email = TextField()
    first_name = TextField()
    last_name = TextField()


def send_welcome_email(user):
    msg = EmailMessage(recipient=user.email)
    msg.send()
```

In this case, it would have been better to define the function interface as:

```
def send_welcome_email(email)
```

so that the function is not coupled with the `User` class.

I know this is a known anti-pattern but I cannot find it. Anyone know what it's called?

Comment: I posted this in a comment below but think it deservers a followup discussion. Let's say in the send_welcome_email() it requires 3-4 more properties from the User class and say User has 10 properties . At which point is it ok to pass the whole object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a name for the anti-pattern, but the rule that this is in violation of is called the [Law of Demeter](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki/LawOfDemeter?LawOfDemeter).

> LoD can be regarded as the principle of assuming "least structural knowledge" (something its creator calls "Structure-shy programming"). The idea is to assume knowledge of no object's internal structure other than your own immediate self.

The way I've heard it described: in a store if you pay a cashier you get your credit card from your wallet and give it to them, rather than hand over the wallet and let them rummage through it. Your example shows the rummaging approach; the function gets the User object and it has to know how to access the email property, which it shouldn't have to know about.

Comment: Let's say in `the send_welcome_email()` it requires 3-4 more properties from the `User` class and say `User` has 10 properties . At which point is it ok to pass the whole object?

Comment: @nathan-hughes - I think Law of Demeter comes pretty close. I love the analogy too!

Comment: @Glide - Good question. Maybe it is better described as a code smell than an anti-pattern.

Comment: @aco: i think this is interesting, thinking of how to address this in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The function has a touch of [the Feature Envy code smell](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FeatureEnvySmell). ("Code smells" are antipatterns, documented in a chapter by Fowler and Beck in [the Refactoring book](http://martinfowler.com/books/refactoring.html), named before the word "antipattern" was in wide use.) Feature Envy is when one module is coupled to another module by calling too many of the other module's methods. In this case one is too many.

The usual fix is to extract a method onto the other module, but that doesn't apply here since there's only one smelly method call. The fix of asking the function's caller to call the method instead works as long as it's OK for the caller to have that coupling to the `User` class.

This does remind one of the [Law of Demeter](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki/LawOfDemeter?LawOfDemeter), a guideline that reduces coupling, but that applies most specifically to a caller calling a method on the result of calling another method, which isn't happening here.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>It sounds like the [Anemic Domain Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model).</strike>

Comment: I don't think that's what @aco is referring to. It is an anemic domain model, but I think the point was that `send_welcome_email` only needs the email, but in the first case the whole user was being passed in.

Comment: Thanks for clarification :-)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the whole purpose of `send_welcome_email` to generate an email for the specific purpose of welcoming the user (i..e need information about the user like name, username, email address)?

Your alternative do not do that.

The method should probably not be in the user class but something like `UserEmailSender` or similar.

My answer is therefore no: It doesn't look like an anti-pattern.

Comment: No, the `send_welcome_email()` only needs an email address. The caller should not have to construct a `User` object in order to call it - that would unnecessarily couple that function to the `User` class.

Comment: Welcome emails typically include a name `"Hi {FirstName} {LastName}"`, and a username: `"To login, use your username: {Username}"`. thus user information is required. But since I don't know how your actual implementation looks like, it's hard to tell in your specific case.

Comment: I should clarify that `send_welcome_email()` is not a method of `User`, it is a completely separate function. This function only uses the email address. It is instantiating an `EmailMessage` object but only passing it the email address, not the first & last name.

Comment: If it only uses the email, well then it should not require the entire user object.